# Magento2: MSP ReCaptcha For product Review

Tags: magento2, module

I have added `MSP ReCaptcha` module its working fine on login etc areas.

now I want to add this on product review page in `magento2` I add this code

```
 <event name="review_controller_product_init">
   <observer name="msp_captcha" instance="MSP\ReCaptcha\Observer\Frontend\ContactFormObserver" />
</event>
```

but getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setRedirect() on null in
```

Comment: Share your observer code

Comment: public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($this->isCheckRequired->execute()) {
            $reCaptchaResponse = $this->responseProvider->execute();
            $remoteIp = $this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();

            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action $controller */
            $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();

            if (!$this->validate->validate($reCaptchaResponse, $remoteIp)) {
                $this->failureProvider->execute($controller ? $controller->getResponse(): null);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Actually, your variable is not object or not found that setRedirect method. Please share your code in your question with full code.

Comment: <event name="review_controller_product_init"> this event is ok you think or i use other event

Comment: Maybe not sure, please share full code of observer in your question.

Comment: simoly i w ant to add captchat in product reivew form

Comment: If this helps https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-recaptcha.html

Comment: Does any one has the answer for this? Even i am facing the similar issue.